# How to configure the performance system parameters of Android to achieve a balanced state

Tags: android, performance, sysctl

For low-end devices (with less than 2GB of RAM), memory often becomes a bottleneck for the system. In such cases, zram is chosen. However, the selection of related parameters for zram can also affect CPU usage. How to balance them?

There are many algorithms for zram, how to choose?
How to select a reasonable value for the size of zram?
When I have different needs, how do I adjust?
Sometimes I want smoother app switching, not easily killed;
and sometimes I need as fast cold start speed as possible.

Can these strategies be dynamically configured and selected?

If only one of these goals needs to be achieved, it can be accomplished by modifying certain configurations. The challenge arises when multiple goals conflict with each other. For example, if you cache a lot of applications, opening an application that has not been cached will result in a cold start and be very slow
I don't know what criteria and methods can objectively evaluate and judge this optimization, in order to achieve a balance between them

Comment: Consider explaining or clarifying your question because right now it doesn't make much sense (at least to me).